# Redux State Not Updated In Dev Tools But Current State Is Being Reflected In Props

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm a redux noob who's trying to get his head around how redux works.
so it's simple.

I have a store

I have a reducer which returns nothing but a single key/pair value
`{authenticated:false}`

I have a useEffect funtion in a child component which just `console.log`'s the props value whenever the props change.

The children component somehow logs the updated props whenever it changes but the changes does not reflect in the redux dev tools.

Below is my code

## index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import ReduxStore from "./ReduxStore/store";
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={ReduxStore}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

## App.js

```
import { connect, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
const { React, useEffect } = require("react");
const App = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
   //PS: i intentionally ignored the action dict inside the reducer
    dispatch({ type: "AppReducer", payload: { type: "checkUserToken" } });
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Props Changed ", props);
// This code above works because it returns the state returned from the reducer anytime it changes
  }, [props]);
  return <>hola </>;
};
const matchStateToProps = (state) => ({ state });
export default connect(matchStateToProps)(App);
```

## store.js

```
const RootReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  return {
    authenticated: false,
  };
  
};

const ReduxStore = createStore(RootReducer);
ReduxStore.subscribe(() => console.log("State Is ", ReduxStore.getState()));
export default ReduxStore;
```

How do i solve this ?
Thanks In Advance

Comment: FWIW, you should really be using [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux), which will drastically simplify your Redux logic.  This includes store setup and writing reducers. Also, we recommend using the React-Redux hooks API instead of connect. I'd recommend going through [our Redux docs tutorials](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/index) to see how to use those.

Comment: yeah about that.
Your tutorials are not simplified enough.
It's very difficult to understand.

I know the docs is the best way to go but it's very confusing

Comment: Sorry to hear that :(  Unfortunately most Redux tutorials online are very outdated and do not show how to use "modern Redux" with RTK.  I'd still recommend trying to read through our docs tutorials if you can.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer to my question.

The only line of code missing was adding

`window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()`  to the `createStore` param

the code should have been

```
const ReduxStore = createStore(
  RootReducer,
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);
```

Comment: Note that with Redux Toolkit you _only_ need to do `configureStore({reducer: rootReducer})`, because it will set up the Redux DevTools for you automatically.

Comment: that was helpful thanks very much